# Jq label and break to break out of control structure

Tags: label, jq, break

I'm trying to learn jq `label` and `break`.

Here's my attempt:
https://jqplay.org/s/YHxn1dRlQO

```
Filter:
label $out | reduce .[] as $item (0; if $item==1 then break $out else .+$item end)

Input:
[3,2,1]

Output:
empty
```

I was expecting output 5.

I don't really know how `label` and `break` works.

Can you explain how to correctly use them with examples?

Comment: Given your input array, `.==1` will never evaluate to true. `$item==3`, `$item==2` and `$item==1`, as well as `.==0`, `.==3` and `.==5`, however, would.

Comment: Thx for that. I tried `label $out | reduce .[] as $item (0; if $item==1 then break $out else .+$item end)` expecting output 5 but it has no output.

Comment: Oh, I see, I have finally caught (sic!) your misunderstanding. See my post.

Answer (score 0):

Given your input array, `.==1` will never evaluate to true. `$item==3`, `$item==2` and `$item==1`, as well as `.==0`, `.==3` and `.==5`, however, would.

And if it does, it still wouldn't output `5` because `break` is treated like an error that was caught.

From the manual:

> The `break $label_name` expression will cause the program to to act as though the nearest (to the left) `label $label_name` produced `empty`.

Therefore

```
label $out | reduce .[] as $item (0;
  if $item==1 then break $out else .+$item end
)
```

will correctly produce `empty`.

You can still capture `empty` though, for instance

```
label $out | reduce .[] as $item (0;
  if $item == 1 then break $out else . + $item end
)? // (.[:index(1)] | add)
```

```
5
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/soSlN-ttVf)

Answer (score 0):

`break` does not work (in the way one might reasonably expect (*) ) with `reduce`.  Whether that is by design or not, I cannot say, but perhaps it's not surprising as `reduce` is intended for reductions.

Apart from `reduce`, though, `break` behaves properly elsewhere, notably with `foreach`.

---

(*) Consider for example:

```
  label $out
  | reduce range(0;10) as $i (0; .+$i | if $i == 4 then ., break $out else . end)
```

One might reasonably expect the accumulated sum (0+1+2+3+4) to be emitted, but instead the result is `empty`.

By contrast, if you replace `reduce` with `foreach`, the result is as expected:

```
0
1
3
6
10
```

Notice that to achieve the effect that is presumably wanted with `reduce`, one can simply use `last` in conjunction with `foreach`:

```
  last(label $out
       | foreach range(0;10) as $i (0; .+$i | if $i == 4 then ., break $out else . end))
```

Comment: It **does** work with `reduce`. The manual even has an example with it: "To break out of a `reduce`, for example: `label $out | reduce .[] as $item (null; if .==false then break $out else ... end)`"

Comment: @pmf - Please see the clarification.

Comment: Hm, I think this is a matter of what is "reasonable to expect". To me, it stands more to reason that in a declarative-style context, if you "break" a computation then it is broken as in not usable, so outputting `empty` is the logical conclusion, but, as always, your (and other's) mileage may vary.